# Add Data Dynamically to HTML Button in HTML page

Tags: html, angular

I have this button, I need to add Pendo Data that is dynamically working based on which button we chose. Mostly this is making the Button unique. When I have a button that is not changing I add like this:

```
                           <button mat-button
                             data-pendo="pendo-prospects-send-application"
                            class='round-button'
                            color='primary'
                            type='button'
                            .....>
                        </button>
```

But sometime I need to add this data to one button that is changing based on CSS class. I am not sure how check for that.

For example I need to add to a button when :

if [class.fa-pencil] then data-pendo "Something"
 if [class.fa-plus] then data-pendo "Something else"

This is the button that changes base on class:

```
                           <button mat-button
                            class='round-button'
                            type='button'
                            [class.disabled-button]='GuidId'
                            color='primary'
                            (click)='onAssignLoanOfficer()'>
                            <i class='fal'
                                [class.fa-pencil]='GuidId'
                                [class.fa-plus]='!GuidId'></i>
                        </button>
```

How I can do that?

Comment: The property GuidId is the one that sets the class... what does prevent you from using this info to take an action inside `onAssignLoanOfficer()` method?

Comment: I mean, you could just do `if(this.GuidId) { // class is fa-pencil } else { // class is fa-plus }`

Comment: @julianobrasil But that is same in both condition, only thing that I can use and is different is the name of the class [class.fa-pencil] and  [class.fa-plus]

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm following your train of thought. I'm also not aware of what pendo-data does, but can't you just do `<div data-pendo={{GuidId ? 'pendo-edit-loan' : 'pendo-Add-loan'}}></div>`. I'm sorry if this example is absurd, but I really don't know Pendo Data.

Comment: @julianobrasil I have added some explanation to my question, Mostly data-pendo is an extra tag that makes than button unique, easily I can add it to a button and will be added to the button element, but this button in changing bases on class, I need to have 2 different data-pendo added. For example: If  class=-class.fa-pencil] then data-pendo="something" if class =   [class.fa-plus] data-pendo is something else, I do not know how to write if statement here.

Comment: if data-pendo is depenendent on class, what's changing the class? This can all be done in javascript.

Comment: @JohnPeters that is only thing changing  [class.fa-pencil] or [class.fa-plus]. I can use angular, but   not sure how.

Comment: My question was, what's changing the class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comments I think this is what you want to do:

```html
<button
  (click)="onAssignLoanOfficer()"
  [class.disabled-button]="GuidId"

  [attr.data-pendo]="GuidId ? 'pendo-edit-loan' : 'pendo-add-loan'"

  class="round-button"
  color="primary"
  type="button">
  <i [class.fa-pencil]="GuidId"
     [class.fa-plus]="!GuidId"
     class="fall">
  </i>
</button>
```

#### ALTERNATIVE:

As a more sophisticated alternative (I really don't know how you intend to use what you're asking for), you can build a directive to add the attribute you want based on a map of class-to-pendo-data conversion information:

```js
@Directive({
  selector: '[addPendoData]'
})
export class AddPendoDataDirective implements AfterViewInit {
  constructor(private _el: ElementRef, private _renderer: Renderer2) {}

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    const pendoData: string | null | undefined = this._getPendoValue();
    if (!pendoData) { return;}

    const $button: HTMLElement = this._el.nativeElement;
    this._renderer.setAttribute($button, 'data-pendo', pendoData);
  }

  private _getPendoValue() {
    const $child: HTMLElement = this._el.nativeElement;
    if(!$child) { return null; }

    const $i: HTMLElement = $child.querySelector('i');
    if(!$i) { return null; }

    const listOfClasses: string[] = $i.className.split(' ');

    if (!(listOfClasses && listOfClasses.length)) { return null; }

    for(const className of listOfClasses) {
      if(PENDO_MAP[className]) { return PENDO_MAP[className]; }
    }

    return null;
  }
}

const PENDO_MAP: { [className: string]: string } = {
  'fa-pencil': 'pendo-edit-loan',
  'fa-plus': 'pendo-add-loan'
  // add other mappings here...
};
```

and you can use it like this:

```html
<button
  (click)="onAssignLoanOfficer()"
  [class.disabled-button]="GuidId"

  addPendoData

  class="round-button"
  color="primary"
  type="button">
  <i [class.fa-pencil]="GuidId"
     [class.fa-plus]="!GuidId"
     class="fall">
  </i>
</button>
```

### I've put together [this stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/httpsstackoverflowcomq610691516433166).

Answer (score 0):

You could define a directive, as julianobrasil suggests.
I want to point a different way to achieve this using `Angular templates`.

Define two buttons, addition and edition, separately.
Put a default where you want to be rendered

```
<div class="action-button" *ngIf="GuidId">
    <!-- Add button -->
    <button mat-button
        data-pendo="pendo-add-loan"
        (click)="add(...)"
        class="round-button"
        color="primary">

        <i class="fal fa-plus"></i>
    </button>
</div>
```

Then, define a `ng-template` tag with the other button definition. A completely fresh new.

```
<ng-template #edit-button>
    <div class="action-button">
        <!-- Edit button -->
        <button mat-button
            (click)="edit(...)"
            data-pendo="pendo-edit-loan"
            class="round-button"
            color="primary">

            <i class="fal fa-pencil"></i>
        </button>
    </div>
</ng-template>
```

Finally, just change the `*ngIf` statement to render either an addition button or an edition one.

```
<div class="action-button" *ngIf="!GuidId else edit-button">
    <!-- Add button here -->
</div>
```

This is a way that scales in order to keep components isolated. The buttons are not related anymore, so you can implement w/o having to condition every style, action, etc.

Hope it helps.